# I am unable to justify text in latex

Tags: justification, ragged2e

when I add

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

17 errors pop up.

The document class I am using is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{aitthesis}
```

as I am writing my thesis. Can anybody help me resolving the matter ?

Comment: The option `document` you passed sets the whole document `RaggedRight`. Avoid this option and use when is nessessary the macros `\RaggedRight` etc. If you need to justify text again use `\justifying` macro. See pages 3-7 of `ragged2e manual`.

Comment: after `\begin{document}` you could add `\justifying` it should solve your problem

Comment: Are the files of the `aitthesis` document class available online? If so, where? And, please tell us why you're loading the`ragged2e` package with the option `document`.

Comment: @mala97 that would be a weird way to get justified text though, as justification is the default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As far as I know if you are using `ragged2e` the default is `flushleft`

Comment: @mala97 no, only if you explicitly specify that with `[document]` There are essentially no valid uses for `\justfying` it is only ever used to correct for earlier errors.

Comment: Welcome to `TeX.SE`

Comment: If you don't load ragged2e, you can still use \raggedright and \fussy or \sloppy.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the global option `document` from the line `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` and kept as `\usepackage{ragged2e}` only, and use the tag `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight`, wherever you need the `unjustified` text